# How do I add HTML code to JSF FacesMessage

Tags: html, jsf, escaping, message

By default, every JSF `FacesMessage` is presented in a single row. I would like to add a HTML line break `<br />` to the message itself, so that the message is shown neatly. I tried it like below

```
message = new FacesMessage("test<br/>test");
```

However, it got escaped by JSF and is shown as literal text. How can I add HTML code to a `FacesMessage` without it getting escaped?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186659/showing-the-jsf-error-messages ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In theory, you want an `escape` attribute for the `h:messages` component like the `h:outputText` has. You're not the only one who wants this, this is requested before more than often, but it's a WONTFIX according the JSF guys.

You have several options:

1. Use `\n` instead of `<br>` and apply CSS accordingly (easiest).

   ```
   #messages td { white-space: pre; }
   ```
2. Create a [custom renderer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-html-in-jsf-messages.html) which extends `MessageRenderer` (bit harder, but nice if you want to cover more HTML than only linebreaks).
3. Gather the messages yourself in some `List` in a bean and display them using [`<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_dataList.html), or when you're already using Facelets instead of JSP, using `<ui:repeat>`. This way you can use `<h:outputText escape="false">` to display the individual messages.
4. Or, when you're already on JSF 2.0, just iterate over [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29) yourself. Each item gives you a [`FacesMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) back which in turn offers several getters. You could then display the summary in a `<h:outputText escape"false" />`.

   ```
   <ul>
       <ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList}" var="facesMessage">
           <li>
               <h:outputText value="#{facesMessage.summary}" escape="false" />
           </li>
       </ui:repeat>
   </ul>
   ```
5. Or, when you're using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), use its [`<o:messages>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/messages) instead which has support for `escape` attribute.

   ```
   <o:messages escape="false" />
   ```

Comment: When you are on JSF 2.0, you can also use the OmniFaces [`<o:messages>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/messages) with the `escape="false"` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC Do you want to link the WONTFIX issue or not? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Primefaces 5.3 support HTML on FacesMessages, just setting `escape="false"` at `messages` component:

```
<p:messages escape="false"/>
```

The `p:growl` supports this too btw.

Answer (score 2):

I followed [this](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/05/adf-basics-how-to-use-facesmessage-to.html) blog.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html><body>");
sb.append("<p>A list of messages are:</p>");
for(String str : listMessages){
      sb.append("Message: ").append(str).append("<br/>");
}  
sb.append("</body></html>");

FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(sb.toString());
message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", message);
```

The key is not to miss the `<html>` and `<body>` tags and closing them properly like a valid HTML. Otherwise HTML tags appear as text on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS class to format the message, as BalusC told you in  your previous question:

[Showing the JSF Error Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186659/showing-the-jsf-error-messages)