# New Line character in FacesMessage Jsf

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I wants to display the error message like,
"The following headers not avail

```
1.Name
2.Roll no
```

How can i show this using faces message in jsf?Please help me.

Comment: Why aren't you adding multiple messages?

Comment: I need to add the all the items using single message only.

Comment: See [How do i add a HTML Break <br /> in the JSF FacesMessage I create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195348/how-do-i-add-a-html-break-br-in-the-jsf-facesmessage-i-create)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without implementing a bizarre hack using javascript and css or without implementing your own JSF messages custom component this is not possible.

You will need to create a new FacesMessage for each line.

Comment: This answer is no longer true. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Simply set `escape="false"` on the `<p:messages>` component [in PrimeFaces 3.3+](https://www.primefaces.org/facesmessage-enhancements/).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using  tag.
You need to render this outputText on submit event and then display message in .
You have to change escape attribute to false and user  tag in you message where you need break.
So in above case take one,
  2.Roll" escape="false" render="your validation"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                 "Title",
                 "<html>List:<ul><li> List item 1;</li><li> List item 2;</li><li> List item 3.</li></ul></html>")
```